# Making my 32-bit program code compile on 64-bit Ubuntu (looking for safe path)

Tags: 64-bit, compiling, 32-bit, c++

I have for the first time installed a 64-bit Ubuntu on my laptop. Now I am looking for a way to compile my old biology C++ project on this OS. I have a .sh file that installs all necessary packages for my project to compile on a newly installed 32-bit Ubuntu. The content of this file is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
apt-get update  # To get the latest package lists
apt-get install build-essential -y
apt-get install freeglut3-dev -y
apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev -y
apt-get install libsdl-image1.2-dev -y
apt-get install libsdl-mixer1.2-dev -y
apt-get install libopenscenegraph-dev -y
```

Now the problem is, after having installed those packages on my 64-bit Ubuntu, and wanting to compile my project with the according Makefile, I get the following error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../../gllib-3.0b3/lib/libgll.a when searching for -lgll
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgll
```

After having checked, I now know that `libgll.a` file was compiled for `elf33-i386` architecture. Because I do not know how to recompile this file for 64-bit architecture, I am pretty sure that I have to compile my entire project in 32-bit architecture.

Long story short, my question now is: How can I make this project compile as a 32-bit application, and run it on 64-bit Ubuntu?

My guess would be, that I have to use the command `dpkg --add-architecture i386` and then manually install the packages of interest with `apt-get install <package-name>:i386`. Problem with that method is, that `apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev:i386` requires me to uninstall the `build-essential` package.

Of course finally I will also have to modify my `makefile`, adding `-m32` to `CXXFLAGS` (and other lines?). I can post my `makefile` if this is required for you to help me. ^^

What I first tried was to just simply install everything the way I had on my previous 32-bit machine.

The problem is, I get the following compilation error: /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../../gllib-3.0b3/lib/libgll.a when searching for -lgll

This made me think that probably my (5 year old) was just not compatible to run as a 64-bit application.

Or would you happen to know if I should be able to compile this as native 64-bit? ^^

Comment: Why would you want to compile for 32 bit on a 64 bit system?

Comment: @MandelBrot Please post additional info in the answer by editing, not in the comments.

Comment: Alright, sorry, I didn't know the policies. I'm going to update my start post now. And just a question. Is Askubuntu the most adequate Forum on Stackexchange to post my question, or are there Stackexchange Forums that are more specialized for my issue?

Answer (score 1):

It is very strange that whatever program you are trying to compile ships a 32 bit binary library instead of its source code, but apparently this library can be found [here](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml), and if you compile that you should get a 64 bit libgll that you should be able to use to compile this program for 64 bit.

Comment: `libgl.a` isn't compiled during my compilation. Actually, this was a file that was given to the students by the professor at the start of the project.

So what I now did, is I installed pygame with the command `apt-get install python-pygame`. I'm sorry I'm not at all familiar with the concept of how and where libraries are stored, so could you tell me where I can find the 64-bit `libgl.a` you were talking about?

Comment: @MandelBrot, that's what I said... I also seem to have linked the wrong URL somehow, but the library I found on that site does not seem to line up with the version you are using, so I would say go ask this professor where the heck he got it from so you can compile it yourself.

Comment: This project ist more than 5 years old. I don't want to disturb my that professor with such a minor problem. I'm not in a hurry to resolve this problem, therefore I'm gonna continue trying to compile my project as a 32-bit binary, as it doesn't seem that a 64-bit version of `libgl.a` can be found on the internet.